# Problema con método next() del objeto ResultSet - Java

Tags: java, jdbc

qué tal?

Les comento, estoy realizando una llamada a una base de datos en Java utilizando el siguiente codigo:

```
private boolean getInvoiceOrdersFromDB(String documentType, String document, int officeId, String channelId, String fromDate, String toDate, MbElement outJsonRoot) {
        try{
            String query = "SELECT Pedidos.PedidosMulticanal.PMuOrderId FROM Pedidos.Clientes, Pedidos.PedidosMulticanal "+
                            "WHERE Pedidos.Clientes.PMuCodigoPedidoMulticanal=Pedidos.PedidosMulticanal.PMuCodigoPedidoMulticanal "+
                            "AND Pedidos.Clientes.PaiCodigoPais=? "+
                            "AND Pedidos.Clientes.CliDocumento=? "+
                            "AND Pedidos.PedidosMulticanal.CanCodigoCanal=? "+
                            "AND Pedidos.PedidosMulticanal.PMuFechaPedido>=? "+
                            "AND Pedidos.PedidosMulticanal.PMuFechaPedido<? "+
                            "AND Pedidos.PedidosMulticanal.SucCodigoSucursal=?;";
            
            Connection c = getJDBCType4Connection("BaseEjemplo", JDBC_TransactionType.MB_TRANSACTION_AUTO );
            PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, documentType);
            pstmt.setString(2, document);
            pstmt.setString(3, channelId);
            pstmt.setString(4, fromDate);
            pstmt.setString(5, toDate);
            pstmt.setInt(6, officeId);
            
            rs  = pstmt.executeQuery();
            
            if (rs.isBeforeFirst()){    
                return createOkResponse(rs, outJsonRoot) ? true : false ;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            String msg = e.getMessage();    
            return false;
        }
    }
```

El método que procesa el ResultSet posee el siguiente código:

```
private boolean createOkResponse(ResultSet rs, MbElement outJsonRoot) {
        
        try{
            //Creación del array en el body de la respuesta JSON -> Estructura del mensaje de salida Root/JSON/Data/[]
            MbElement outJsonData = outJsonRoot.createElementAsLastChild(MbJSON.ARRAY, MbJSON.DATA_ELEMENT_NAME, null);
            
            //Iteración en el resultSet para agregar los elementos 
            while(rs.next()){
                outJsonData.createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_VALUE, null ,rs.getString("PMuOrderId").toString());
            }
            
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            String msg2 = e.getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Sucede que se está disparando un error a la hora de llegar al método "rs.next()" dentro del while.
El mensaje que se ataja mediante la exepcion es:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.
```

Realmente no entiendo qué puede ser. La query sólo trae una columna de tipo Varchar (la cual contiene 57 rows para el ejemplo con el que estoy probando ).

La base es SQL Server 2014

[image: Imagen de ejemplo del resultado de la query]

Muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

El campo PMuFechaPedido en tu base de datos es de tipo date, al momento de establecer el valor en las consultas estas usando setString. Intenta modificando tu código para que conviertas a tipos fechas, por ejemplo setDate(CAST_VALOR);